# get the EPSG code from openlayers 3 layer

Tags: openlayers-3

This is my OSM layer in openlayers 3.9.0.

```
var layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM(

        {
        attributions: [
          new ol.Attribution({
            html: 'All maps &copy; ' +
                '<a href="http://www.opencyclemap.org/">OpenCycleMap</a>'
          })
        ]
      }             

    ),
    opacity: 0.8,
    brightness: 0.8
});
```

And now I want to get the `EPSG code` of the layer to check it so I do like

```
var a = layer.getProjection().getCode();
alert(a);
```

and I get the error `layer.getProjection is not a function`.

What am I missing?

Please help me

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should [`getProjection`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/apidoc/ol.source.OSM.html#getProjection) on `ol.source.OSM` rather than `ol.layer.Tile`, so:

```
layer.getSource().getProjection().getCode()
```

Comment: It worked. Out of curiosity, I just cannot understand why I need the `getSource`, since I get the projection of the layer with `getProjection`. Any help? Thanks

Comment: Because `ol.layer.Tile` knows nothing about projection.